# pause youtube video on next slide using cycle plugin

Tags: jquery, youtube, slideshow, jquery-cycle

I have an embedded YouTube video in a slideshow (MaxImage using the Cycle Plugin) that I am trying to pause once the user clicks to the next slide. There is a built in function for HTML5 videos, but I'm just not sure of how to do the same for YouTube. Thanks!

Notice the before and after functions..

```
$(function(){
$('#maximage').maximage({
    cycleOptions: {
        fx: 'fade',
        speed: 600,
        timeout: 0,
        prev: '.prev',
        next: '.next',
        pause: 1,
        before: function(last,current){
            if(!$.browser.msie){
                // Start HTML5 video when you arrive
                if($(current).find('video').length > 0) $(current).find('video')[0].play();
                }
            },
        after: function(last,current){
            if(!$.browser.msie){
                // Pauses HTML5 video when you leave it
                if($(last).find('video').length > 0) $(last).find('video')[0].pause();
            }
        },    

        onFirstImageLoaded: function(){
        jQuery('#loader').hide();
        jQuery('#maximage').fadeIn(200);
    }
});         
});
```

Comment: Are you embedding the YouTube video as an iframe? You should be using the API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Operations

Comment: yes it's in an iframe. how would I connect the pause function the next slide though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make use of the [iFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player), otherwise you cannot interact with the video due to cross-domain policy:

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}
$('#maximage').maximage({
    cycleOptions: {
        fx: 'fade',
        speed: 600,
        timeout: 0,
        prev: '.prev',
        next: '.next',
        pause: 1,
        before: function(last,current){
            if(player != null) player.playVideo()
        },
        after: function(last,current){
            if(player != null) player.pauseVideo()
        },    

        onFirstImageLoaded: function(){
        jQuery('#loader').hide();
        jQuery('#maximage').fadeIn(200);
    }
});
```

Comment: I read through the API documents and tried your code, but something must be breaking. My slideshow refuses to load. Maybe it's just too late or something ..

Comment: You may need to move your `maximage` call into a `onPlayerReady` function to ensure it's only initialised when the youtube clip is loaded

Comment: got it working! just needed to hook up the player differently. one more thing though because it pauses when going to the next slide, but when going back to the video it plays for a second and then pauses again. sort of hiccups. is there a way to resume the video when navigating back to it? sorry for being a pain.